# shalt: used with the pronoun thou or its relative equivalent

Tags: relative-pronouns, thou-thee-thy, shall-future

> **Shalt** is used with the pronoun *thou* or its relative equivalent https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shalt

What does *relative equivalent* mean here?

Comment: They've got this wrong. They probably mean the possessive form of the pronoun: 'My destrier is a noble beast; thine shalt fetch but a handful of groats at the horse fayre.'

Comment: I'da thought it meant a relative pronoun coreferential to _thou_, like _Thou, who shalt die in infamy!_, but frankly that doesn't sound very grammatical to me. Pronouns, especially second-person ones, don't take to relative clauses very well.